# How to dynamically choose the separator used by OpenCSV application?

Tags: java, opencsv, separator

I've a code that reads a CSV file e convert the content to Java objects using `CsvToBean`.

```
public static <T> List<T> parseInputStreamFromCsv(InputStream inputStream, Class<T> clazz) {
  try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
    CsvToBean<T> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<T>(reader)
        .withType(clazz)
        .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
        .build();

    return csvToBean.parse();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new ConversionFailedException("Error converting CSV");
  }
}
```

Sometimes a user uploads a CSV using comma as separator, and then, other users uploads with semicolon as separator.

My questions is that exists a way to set the separator dynamically in my `CsvToBeanBuilder`, creating a way to convert both files (with comma and semicolon) without any problem. Thanks!

My questions is that exists a way to set the separator dynamically in my `CsvToBeanBuilder`, creating a way to convert both files (with comma and semicolon) without any problem.

Comment: How would you know, if say a user uploaded a file that was meant to be comma-separated but contained semicolons in the values? What springs to mind is to use a `BufferedInputStream` and mark/reset it, having read a few lines but it would be much better to get a standardised input

Comment: Yeah, would be! The idea here is take as standard the semicolon, the doubt is just if would exists a way to prevent processing errors caused by the delimiter. Anyways, thanks for your answer @g00se !

Comment: @JoãoPedroPeres Added an answer that should fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach will work with both separator chars, `;` and `,`:

### Parsing with dynamic *separator* detection

*Note:

As per OP's requirement, the below method support the two main characters for separating row entries.*

```
public static <T> List<T> parseFromCsvWithSeparatorDetection(
                          InputStream inputStream, Class<T> type, String[] columns)
                          throws IOException, CsvException {

    final StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
      int c;
      while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
        textBuilder.append((char) c);
      }
    }
    final String csvContent = textBuilder.toString();
    final char detectedSeparator;
    if(csvContent.contains(";")) {
      detectedSeparator = ';'; // semicolon case
    } else {
      detectedSeparator = ','; // default case
    }
    try (Reader reader = new StringReader(csvContent)) {
      ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<T> strategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<>();
      strategy.setColumnMapping(columns);
      strategy.setType(type);
      CsvToBean<T> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<T>(reader)
              .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
              .withSeparator(detectedSeparator)
              .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
              .build();
      return csvToBean.parse();
    } 
  }
```

### Usage example

```
String[] columns = new String[]{"a", "b"};
InputStream in = ... // <-- set/obtain InputStream here

try {
    List<Bean> objects = CSVUtils.parseFromCsvWithSeparatorDetection(in, Bean.class, columns);
} catch (IOException | CsvException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Given that the class `Bean` has two String attributes `a` and `b`, a no-arg constructor (and getter/setter methods).

### Demo csv data

```
A1;B1
A2;B2
```

and

```
A1,B1
A2,B2
```

I tested the above with 17 and OpenCSV 5.7.1, should also work for older or more recent 5.x versions.

### Cave!

The above approach should **only** be used if memory for processing is not an issue at runtime. Reason: The `inputStream` is fully consumed and read into memory - yet, only once. Nevertheless, this could be problematic under *low resources* environments *or* with very large (, and very likely (!) with HUGE) csv files (with potentially millions of rows.